# Looking for TV show or movie with monsters that came to life from old film reels

Tags: story-identification, tv, horror

I am trying to remember the name of what I think was a TV show. This episode featured a film warehouse where monsters were coming to life from the old films. If I remember right, the hero saves the day by burning the warehouse, and as the film burns the monsters vanish.

I think this was in black and white, I remember seeing it more than once when I was kid so probably back in the 70s.

I think it was from an anthology program like Twilight Zone or Outer limits.

I think that various bad guys came to life from the film reels inducing classic movie monsters.

Comment: http://turtlepedia.wikia.com/wiki/Rondo_in_New_York

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: There was a story similar to this in one of the *Borderlands* collections, where the magic that made the projector run infected the film and the characters stepped off the screen and wandered around town.

Comment: I seem to remember that the classic movie monsters like the Mummy and the Werewolf were coming to life from these film reels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Circle of Fear" (1972-1973 TV series)?
Episode: Graveyard Shift

This sounds like episode 19, starring Patty Duke and John Astin, called "Graveyard Shift", although it's in color. The plot details seem to match up and the decade is the right one. It's also an anthology series as you remembered. This series only lasted 1 season. Below is a user review of this episode from IMDb:

> Not the best the series had to offer, but not the worst either. It's a
>   fun concept---the idea that classic film horror characters have come
>   to life and haunt their old studio. Actually, I felt a bit sympathetic
>   toward them! It's always enjoyable to see Patty Duke and John Astin
>   (who were married in real life at this time), though the script
>   doesn't really give them a whole lot to do. And I got a kick out of
>   seeing series creator William Castle make a brief cameo as the head of
>   the studio.
>
> I remember finding this very scary indeed when I watched it as a
>   eight-year-old, but re-watching as an adult I'm afraid the five film
>   monsters just aren't all that frightening---they're more silly than
>   scary, in fact. Overall, I'll give this an "eh..." sort of rating; it
>   isn't terrible, but its primary charm is the result of nostalgia,
>   rather than from being a solid, creepy story.

I didn't think they had too many episodes available, but I found this one on YouTube. You can watch the entire episode below, the film burning scene starts at about 46:50.

Comment: I knew I'd seen that somewhere recently.

Comment: Yes this is the show I remembered! I think I remembered it as B/W because of the dark night time scenes. So nice that I was able to watch again also.

Answer (score 3):

This was done in an episode of *Charmed* (Season 2, Episode 18: "Chick Flick").

Comment: How was it resolved?

Comment: Spoiler alert: https://charmed.wikia.com/wiki/Chick_Flick/Plot

Comment: *"Phoebe and Piper escape, leaving Billy in the movie. The Demon of Illusion comes on screen and taunts the sisters, but Prue remotely stops the projector motor, burning the Demon under the bright light."*

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it wasn't [Monster Squad ?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monster_Squad) from 1987 ?

Comment: Are there any details you can remember that suggest similarity. As opposed to simply providing a link, it's good to provide the information in your answer here, so as long as this site remains alive the information will exist, regardless if other sites collapse. Also, your timelines don't seem to match up if the original user asking watched it in the 70s

Comment: Link-only answers are [considered poor quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) and may be deleted. You should add some quotes or images to reinforce your answer.